# Filtering JTable with JComboBox generates ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, swing, jtable, indexoutofboundsexception, jcombobox

I created a GUI which contains a JComboBox and a JTable. The JTable is filled with data from an Access Database. The JComboBox is used to filter the JTable.
When I select an item from the JComboBox the JTable shows the correct data. But if I first select a row from the JTable and select another item from the JComboBox I get the following error:

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

What’s the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Any time you throw an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException the issue lies in that you are trying to select data that lies outside the working area for the data set (Array in this example. Arrays use 0 based indexing). First I would ensure the data in your JTable is correct, then I would look at how the relationship between the JTable and JComboBox is defined.

Would be easier if you also included some of your code so we could actually see the error in your design. Best of luck!